# Linux 版の Chrome を使って Twitter 上で漢字入力を行うと確定できなくなる

Tags: linux, google-chrome

**再現環境:**
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
日本語入力 ibus +mozc  (上記OSでdefaultのもの)
Chrome 88.0.4324.182

Twitterのweb版でtweet入力しようとしたときに、例えば以下のような入力を行うとします。

```
総理大臣。
こんにちわ。
```

"そうりだいじん" を変換して　"総理大臣" に下線がついている状態（未確定）で　"。"を入力すると　"総理大臣"の下線は消えますが　次にくる　"。"に下線が残って、Enterを押しても消せなくなってしまいます。（確定できなくなる）

いったん"総理大臣"の下線が消えるようにEnterを押して確定させてから"。"を打つ、または、"。"を二重に打つ場合には（それは正規な入力方法ですらないですが）、このような現象は起きません。

この現象が起こったあとに、マウスクリックで確定させるなどして、入力を進めていくと、突然入力内容がごっそり消えてしまったりします。

なお、Firefoxで同じことをしたら同様の現象は起きませんでした。

本当は、逐一、しっかり変換確定させていけばいいのですが、省略していく方法が染み付いているので、難しいです。

回避方法があるので、実用上はそこまで困るわけではないのですが、原因を知ることで、日本語入力がらみの知見がえられるかと思い、質問させていただきました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: これ Twitterの問題でしょうね。文字タイプ中に(#ハッシュタグとか) リアルタイムに何かしてるタイプはよくこうなりますね。ここstackoverflowも時々入力変になります (Markdownの修飾系統？)。Webアプリ提供側(Twitter)に現象知らせて対応待つのがよいかも？

Comment: 参考:[ブラウザでIME確定時のEnterキー入力をハンドリングしない](https://qiita.com/ledsun/items/31e43a97413dd3c8e38e)

Comment: ここまでの現象ではないですが、下線がついた状態で次の文字をうつと、後からうった最初の文字入力がキャンセルされてしまうということが、ちらほらありますね。WEB系の技術をつかった他のアプリなどでも。

Answer (score 1):

以前から発生しているもので、このIssueがそれに該当します。
https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/2005